# Android Type error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml

Im very new to android/java and have been following a few youtube tutorials and have run myself into a serious problem on one of my xml layouts.

Basically im getting an 'Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)' error on the `android:hint` of my code in the `EditText` part. Could anyone give me a clue what Ive done wrong? (Btw theres a chance the code could be a complete mess as i have been messing around just trying to get it to work!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Type a command"
    android:inputType="true">
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="@string/Try Command" >
    </Button>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:checked="true"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:text="@string/ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Invalid"
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Close the bracket of the Textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Invalid">   <--- you forgot to close bracket here
                                 ^^^  
</TextView>
```

And in your `EditText` you are setting hint from your `string.xml`

And be sure there is no problem in your `string.xml`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="SOME HINT" <----    Just try this testing purpose only
    android:inputType="true">
</EditText>
```

Comment: Thanks for that guys. I have closed the text view but still my problem persists. I now have an issue with my other classes erroring with 'R cannot be resolved'